# PDO::quote for oracle

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle, pdo

I have pdo_oci driver, successful pdo connection to oracle database. And I have a query that needs double quotes, so my question is: Why pdo_oci::quote doesnt work?

Example:

```
$dsn = 'oci:dbname=' . $dbUrl . '/' . $dbName . ';charset=utf8';
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_BOTH,
             PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
             PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false);
$conn = new PDO($dsn,$db_username,$db_password,$options);
$tmp = 'temp';
var_dump('select * from' . $conn->quote($tmp));

result: string(13) "select * from"
```

I'm asking this because I have few classes, that use pdo::quote(). All is fine while I'm only using MySQL, but now I need oracle. So if I can't figure out why pdo_oci quote() is not workin, I will have to change every quote method used to some of my own, or override pdo::quote ? Though I wouldn't want to do that.

EDIT: since some take this example for granted, I can give you one that's working with mysql and has proper quote() usage:

```
$sql = 'SELECT modelID FROM statements
           WHERE modelID = ' .$this->modelID .'
           AND subject ='   .$this->dbConn->quote($row[0]) .'
           AND predicate =' .$this->dbConn->quote($row[1]) .'
           AND object ='    .$this->dbConn->quote($row[2]) .'
           AND l_language=' .$this->dbConn->quote($row[3]);
```

See what I mean? and this is just one of many queries that I'd nee to change if I can't make quote() work.

Comment: The manual says "Not all PDO drivers implement this method" and the Oracle driver is experimental (Oracle doesn't work on it and the community is not active). Is it possible to just switch to prepared statements?

Comment: Do you quite realize what this function do? From the code you posted one can tell that you don't.

Comment: Good point... Quoting a table name will just corrupt the query. I had overlooked that.

Comment: This was just an example, and I know that's not how you use quote(), my point was that it doesn't work. I wanted to know if this a driver problem and if anybody has some solutions, not to tell me that my example is wrong. Might as well have written simple string isntead of query...all I needed was to check if pdo_oci::quote works at all.

Comment: this function is useless. You ought to use parameters instead.

Answer (score -1):

that's **improper** quote usage from mysql example.

Here *is* a proper one:

```
$sql = 'SELECT modelID FROM statements
       WHERE modelID = ?
       AND subject = ?
       AND predicate = ?
       AND object = ?
       AND l_language= ?';
```

Follow this pattern with Oracle as well.